# Visual Studio 2013 publish failed max connections exceeded

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish

I was publishing using VS Express 2013 for Web and had a sockets error on one of the dlls while publishing and now I can't publish at all - I received a VS error that says The maximum number of connections for this site has been exceeded. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS.  The url referenced in the error doesn't even address the error and I've googled with no luck. I have tried deleting everything from the host and starting from scratch and still no luck; web host has no idea how to fix.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  I'm getting desperate.

Comment: Just ran into this same issue publishing to an Azure website...will report back if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks, this is driving me nuts.  Web host is unresponse. I've tried everything I can think of, completely deleted everything including domain from web host website panel, added everything back, deleted temp files from local IIS, using different solution changeset just downloaded - and still same error.

Comment: I ended up working around this by setting up my solution to build/deploy to Azure out of TFS rather than manually deploying from Visual Studio.  When I started getting this error I was trying to publish through a VPN...I think that has something to do with it.  Are you connecting to your host through a VPN?

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I'm using wireless router/ISP provider to connect. I can connect/publish to a subdomain (and to other domains) but not main domain.  I'm going to try with VS2012 and then I'll download TFS and try that if VS2012 doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Error was caused by a 10054 socket error (basically host dropped connection).  After 3 days webhost finally **restarted Web Management Services** and problem was fixed.  Then I got 1/2 way thru publishing and got the same 10054 socket error and then max connections error.  I was publishing a lot of files and it appears that host had a connection time out.  I got in chat with host and asked them to **restart Web Mgmt Svcs** again, waited 20 mins and voila - I was able to publish again.  Now I am watching publish and if I see the first socket error I cancel the publish so that it doesn't hit the max site connections error.  Then I start publishing again and it picks right up where it left off.  Nothing I could do on my end to fix it (believe me I tried everything).

Comment: This error happens every time I am publishing a large number of files.  This month when it happened the webhost forgot to restart their web deploy service when they restarted Web Mgmt Svc, so it took another day for them to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Even i get this issue now and then but not necessary to reset web Management Service. You can go to azure website dashboard and reset your web site/ Application first and check.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I opened the Windows Azure item in the "Server Explorer" went to the
Storage item in the tree select Blobs/wad-control-container and delete all the items in the list

Answer (score 0):

In MS Deploy Server (IIS Server)

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3]
"MaxSiteConnections"=dword:00000010

then reboot windows

Answer (score 0):

Thank @LuvAspNet for saving my time.

For others who need more information, you could **restart Web Management Services** by creating a .bat file with this command (or run directly in cmd) and run as administrator

```
net stop wmsvc 

net start wmsvc 

pause
```