# The maximum number of connections for this site has been exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

When trying to publish my site using a web deploy I am getting following error:

> Error 1 Web deployment task failed. (The maximum number of connections for this site has been exceeded.
>
> Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEEDED_MAX_SITE_CONNECTIONS.)

My website is hosted over a shared host. I already raised this issue to the hosting provider and asked them to [restart "Web Management Services"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22431827/visual-studio-2013-publish-failed-max-connections-exceeded) in reply of which they said that they have "restarted publishing service on server". But this error is still not resolved.

What else should I do? Is there something I should check on my side or is it totally a server/hosting provider’s issue?

Comment: Error was caused by a 10054 socket error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have a ton of traffic on this site or the hoster is oversubscribing the box.  An IIS restart may fix it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Error was caused by a 10054 socket error (basically host dropped connection).    you publishing a lot of files and it appears that host had a connection time out..  watching publish and if you see the first socket error   cancel the publish so that it doesn't hit the max site connections error. Then  start publishing again and it picks right up where it left off.